# Homestead not loading web page

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have searched and tried everywhere for something that might fix this but whenever I have a new homestead code folder, it doesn't work when I use vagrant and virtualbox. I have checked my hosts files and every file. No error shows up but it clearly doesn't work. I have also enabled virtualization on my CPU. Below is my current homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

folders:
    - map: C:/Laravel/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/homestead/public
    - map: homestead1.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/homestead1/public

    - map: coursework.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/coursework/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I am trying to just get coursework.test to work but I'm sure its wrong on both of them

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way you use your slashes.

```
 - map: C:/Laravel/code
```

has to be

```
- map: C:\Laravel\code
```

Another problem you will be walking against is that you do not have a database.

Enable mariadb or something else in your features tab